# Underscore JS: reducing into an array causes undefined method error on the accumulator

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, reduce

I have code which looks similar to this, which I'm trying to use to produce an array consisting of three sub-arrays:

```
f = [1, 2.5, 3, 10]
p = [1.2, 5.1, 6.3, 11]
r = [1, 1, 1, 1]

coords = _.reduce([f, p, r], function(memo, series){
    if(series.length){
        memo.push(_.map(series, function(s, i){
            return {x: s, y: i*100};
        }));
    }
}, []);

console.log(coords);
```

The end result should look like:

```
[
  [{x:1,y:100},{x:2,y:2.5}...],
  [{x:1,y:12},{x:2,y:51}...]
]
```

However, when I attempt to execute the code, it returns `cannot read property push of undefined`. When I inspect the error in Chrome, it points me to the `memo.push` line.  The code *seems* ok to me, but I can't figure out where my error is.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must `return` something from your reduce callback to become the new accumulator value. Otherwise `memo` will come back as `undefined` in the next iteration and end result…

A `return memo;` would fix this, however I feel that you actually don't want to use `reduce`:

```
var coords = _.map(_.filter([f, p, r], function(series) {
    return series.length; // > 0
}), function(nonemptyseries) {
    return _.map(nonemptyseries, function(s, i){
        return {x: s, y: i*100};
    });
});
```

Comment: Returning got it!  Also, why would you suggest map + filter over reduce?

Comment: @KevinWhitaker: Because that's what your function is actually doing, and it's more descriptive :-) No ugly `push` calls needed.

Comment: You may also consider `_.chain` rather than nesting multiple `map` and `filter` calls (I find it easier to read).

Comment: @ssube: Yes, I thought of it (or better indentation), but basically it's a personal choice and I just used the same non-OOP style as the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The `_.reduce` method needs to return some value, for the next iteration to take as input.

If you step through the code (put a `debugger` statement before the `_.reduce`), you can see that it succeeds the first time, but `memo` is undefined on the second loop.

In this case, you likely want to return `memo` from the reduce, whether you've added new elements to it or not (if the series was empty, keep going to the next series).

Something like:

```js
f = [1, 2.5, 3, 10]
p = [1.2, 5.1, 6.3, 11]
r = [1, 1, 1, 1]

coords = _.reduce([f, p, r], function(memo, series) {
  if (series.length) {
    memo.push(_.map(series, function(s, i) {
      return {
        x: s,
        y: i * 100
      };
    }));
  }
  return memo;
}, []);

console.log(coords);
```